# blackberry playbook no-index flag

Tags: android, filesystems, blackberry-playbook

I have a simple android application, that stores data into Android/data/{application-name} folder. It is saved in "data.xml" file.

I have converted this app for playbook. Everything works fine, except that this data file is listed in builtin file browser in documents library and user can delete it without any warning.

Is there any way, how can I block indexig of my data folder?
I have tryed .noindex and .metadata_never_index but nothing works.

Using some another extension is my last option.

Thanks for your help.